# How can I get the list of GPU cards to which are connected monitors?

Tags: windows, opengl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

How can I get the list of GPU cards to which are connected monitors?

Can I get a list with the parameters: pciBusID, pciDeviceID, pciDomainID?

- OS: Windows 7
- GPUs: nVidia GeForce/Quadro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use utility **nvidia-smi**, which contained in the nVidia Video Drivers, to indicate to which GPU-card display is connected (only for professional GPU-card: Quadro / Tesla):

- **Windows:** C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi.exe
- **Linux:** /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvidia-smi

example of nvidia-smi output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 332.88     Driver Version: 332.88         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K4000       WDDM  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   30C    P8     9W /  87W |   3027MiB /  3071MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GT 640     WDDM  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   27C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |   2005MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Quadro K4000       WDDM  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 30%   34C    P8    11W /  87W |   3028MiB /  3071MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Where **Disp.A** - Shows the on which GPU-card Display is Active:

- Off - display is not connected
- On - display is connected
- N/A - unknown (for not professional cards: GeForce)

Then we can say, that display is connected to GPU: **2  Quadro K4000  0000:03:00.0**.